# BASH: Generating pattern from filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell, design-patterns, scripting

I have files in a directory as

```
file_01_20_01_2020.txt
file_02_20_01_2020.txt
otherfile_01_28_01_2020.txt
otherfile_02_18_01_2020.txt
otherfile_03_18_01_2020.txt
```

I want to get output as

```
*20_01_2020.txt
*28_01_2020.txt
*18_01_2020.txt
```

Comment: You want a literal `*` glob on the file names?

Comment: Yes, because later i want to use those for another job

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Why these globs and not `*`, `*.txt` or `*_2020.txt`, all of which match the same filenames?

Comment: I was trying to use uniq but , its not working out

Comment: that other guy :
I want to get the pattern as  an output , i don't want to use pattern as an input.

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
ls *txt | sed -r 's/^.*_(.._01_2020.txt)$/*\1/' | sort -u
*18_01_2020.txt
*20_01_2020.txt
*28_01_2020.txt
```

Comment: Thanks , It Did worked .
In my case i used :


ls *txt | sed -r 's/^.*_(.._.._2020.txt)$/*\1/' | sort -u


to include other months as well

Comment: Is the method above self-explanatory enough, or do you require an explanation?

Comment: Self Explanatory :) .
Thanks again .